# How to make a function infer types based on array with sub properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm having an issue creating a function signature that can infer a union type based on an array of objects with a property that is of that type. It works if it is solely an array of objects/types but I feel like it should work in this manner as well. In case it's not clear, in the following example I want the inferred function signature to be `func<ClassA | ClassB>(arr: Array<Config<ClassA | ClassB>>)`

```
interface Base {
    thing: number;
}
class ClassA implements Base {
    public propA!: number;
    public thing!: number;
}
class ClassB implements Base {
    public propB!: number;
    public thing!: number;
}
interface Config<T extends Base> {
    cls: new() => T;
}

function func<T extends Base>(arr: Array<Config<T>>) {}

func([]);

func([
  { cls: ClassA },
]);

// Doesn't compile
func([
  { cls: ClassA },
  { cls: ClassB },
]);

// Does compile
func<ClassA | ClassB>([
  { cls: ClassA },
  { cls: ClassB },
]);
```

Heres an example on stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-array-subprop-type-infer

If you look at line 42 you can see that it is correctly inferring the type as `ClassA | ClassB` when its not a sub property. But on line 24 it is not inferring it as that type. It is only grabbing the type of the first element in the array so the function signature when hovering over it is `ClassA` (or on stackblitz it's showing the base class). I want this to work with any number of types so adding them to the function template param is not good enough.

Comment: This will work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyRyYAFqAOYBcyIArgLYBG0A3AQL4EIA2mGyAMJ8MGAILJgDAA48IDCOAHosyPIWLS6THsATJpUAPbSxAQhr1mbAsQPbd+spQu1GLKO3xd8vfkJEMVEkZOQUlNEwcW00HPQNjaVRXKw8vOy0deOcQChT3G28CUEhYRBRBIxAYYAoAHgAVZAgAD0gQABNlKIA+NRiiXgxLCAB3AAoASmQAXj6Grx8CGDoQBDBgKuQVtbqAVWa2xS6hKpr6lQgenvG4KCgaMXu4AE99nunsZCX8HYRxgDaAzUyCGNGE-AkHAANMCvmCAvxgjCCABdSZeIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to force TypeScript to infer

```
Array<Config<ClassA | ClassB>>
```

When it's trying to infer

```
Array<Config<ClassA> | Config<ClassB>>
```

In general, these kinds of relationships are not interchangeable. While it may feel awkward as a declaration, what you can do to allow inference of the correct type is

```
function func<T extends Config<Base>>(arr: Array<T>) {}
```

But then the explicit call would have to be

```
func<Config<ClassA> | Config<ClassB>>([
  { cls: ClassA },
  { cls: ClassB },
]);
```

Comment: Ya I was looking at that solution from the comment, unfortunately that locks in the generic type of `Config` to be `Base` so if I were to add a property to the Config, for example, `prop: keyof T;` then the only thing I can do is what is in base. so `{ cls: ClassA, prop: 'thing' }` works but `{ cls: ClassA, prop: 'propA' }` does not work. Is there a way to make it keep the templated class? So this answer is about half correct, unfortunately the example I gave was too simple for my actual use case. My bad.

Comment: @AdamKeenan I'm glad you realize the example you gave was too simple. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to point that out. But to my knowledge it seems you have to make a choice between automatic inference and fine-tune type parameter constraints. If I were in your position I'd personally prefer to use the signature you had in your question and explicitly pass the type parameter, since your `Config<>` interface does not appear to want to be covariant.

Comment: Just found out that defining the function as `function func<T extends Config<ClassA> | Config<ClassB>>(arr: Array<T>) {}` works the way I want. if `cls` is `ClassA` then `prop` must be a property of ClassA and the same for ClassB. But obviously this is hard coded so ;D